# Getting rid of duplication in a VB list box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using ASP/VB, I'm trying to get rid of some duplication in a list box that is coming from an XML document.

Sorry if this is a daft question, I'm new to this.

I've tried various things, but nothing has worked.  Here is the code - thanks for any help / assistance!

```
Function getAssets(ByVal siteid As String) As String

    Dim oAssets As New Xteam.XteamWebService
    Dim strAssets As String = ""
    Dim oDoc As New XmlDocument
    'Dim oNode As XmlNode

    strAssets = oAssets.ReadHAssetCodes(siteid)

    oDoc.LoadXml(strAssets)

    For Each Node As XmlNode In oDoc.SelectSingleNode("XteamAssets")
        lstHAssets.Items.Add(New ListItem(Node("hassetdescription").InnerText, Node("hassetcode").InnerText))




    Next

    lstHAssets.Items.Insert(0, "--Please Select--")


    Return "ToSender"

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way but this will work.

```
Function getAssets(ByVal siteid As String) As String        
Dim oAssets As New Xteam.XteamWebService      
Dim strAssets As String = ""      
Dim oDoc As New XmlDocument      '
Dim oNode As XmlNode        
strAssets = oAssets.ReadHAssetCodes(siteid)        
oDoc.LoadXml(strAssets)   
Dim strAryUniqueValues as string() 
Dim strUniqueValues as string = ""
Dim i as int = 0
Dim strSearchPair as string   
For Each Node As XmlNode In oDoc.SelectSingleNode("XteamAssets") 
    strSearchPair = "~" & Node("hassetdescription").InnerText & "/" & Node("hassetcode").InnerText & "~"
    ' see if these values have been included already, if not then add them
    if instr(strUniqueValues,strSearchPair) = -1 then         
        strAryUniqueValues(i) = strSearchPair
        strUniqueValues = strUniqueValues & strAryUniqueValues(i)    
        i = i + 1
    end if   
Next  
'now loop back through and build your listbox
Dim strAryPair as string()
For each strPair in strAryUniqueValues 
    strAryPair = split(strPair,"/") 
    lstHAssets.Items.Add(New ListItem(Replace(strAryPair(0),"~",""),Replace(strAryPair(1),"~","")) 
Next 
  lstHAssets.Items.Insert(0, "--Please Select--")         
  Return "ToSender"    
End Function
```